# data structure for storing height and weight (etc) over time for multiple users in mysql

Tags: mysql, structure, normalization

I am trying to develop an application for my localhost on which I can track physical attributes (ht, weight, body water, body fat, etc) over time to compare to caloric intake for the purposes of meal planning, etc. Here's what I have right now:

```
DB surname
 TBL home
  memberID (tiny int, 1, auto increment, primary key)
  name (varchar, 30)
  gender (char, 1) ->value should be m or f, but this isn't defined anywhere
  birthdate (datetime)
```

for storing the physical data over time I have considered having a table with a three-column primary key (date, person, type of measurement) with regular single column indexes on each column so that I can look up all entries for a date OR for a person OR for a measurement type. Like this:

```
DB surname
 TBL stats (or something to that effect)
  date (datetime, PK1, index)
  memberFK (tiny int, 1, PK2, index)
  type (varchar, 3, PK3, index) -> possible values should be ht | wt | fat | wat maybe others will also become necessary
  value (decimal, 4/1) -> store all values in nnn.n format in a particular system (ie metric) and do any conversions, add units, etc when the data is called
```

This still seems to create a lot of excess redundancy, so I thought of maybe storing each users measurements in a table in their own database, like so:

```
DB user1
 TBL stats
  date (datetime, PK1, index)
  type (varchar, 3, PK2, index)
  value (decimal, 4/1)
```

This seems to clean it slightly by removing a column from the foreign key (and the table altogether), but also prevents me from utilizing foreign keys between this table and other nutrition-related tables that are not user-specific. On the other hand, I plan on developing applications for other household topics in which there is general data and user-specific data, so maybe this is the best way if there are good ways of using data between databases like that.

So neither of these seems quite right to me, but I am at a loss as to how to make them better. I am tending towards the second example, provided I can figure out ways to retain the integrity of my data. Please make any comments of suggestions you think will help. Thank you!

Comment: It seems like serious overkill to use one database per user.  How familiar are you with how databases are typically designed?  The database schema of blog or forum packages might be worth checking out.

Comment: You _are_ aware `TINYINT` holds max 127 users (255 unsigned)? Not _very_ ambitious... And a db (or even table) per user, that way madness lies.. Your first instinct of `(member_id, measurement_type, date, value)` is spot on, and not in the least overcomplicated.

Comment: I am in the process of learning database design as I go, I have been messing with mysql on and off for about 3 years. I also plan to store things like individual song ratings for each user, I might store things like favourite foods for each using for quick access when doing meal planning and such, or other types of data that is specific to a user, so that was why I was considering the separate database for each user.

Comment: Tiny Int: this is intended for use by a family or a household, not for any user using the internet, so tiny int is perfect is it not? Am I missing something?

Comment: Wrikken: the 3-column foreign key seemed a bit overkill for defining only one column (value), am I wrong about that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I would do it

```
DB healthstats
    TABLE user
        memberID (int*, auto increment, unsigned zerofill, primary key)
        name (varchar, 50)
        gender (char, 1) ->value should be m or f, but this isn't defined anywhere
        birthdate (datetime)

    TABLE reading
        readingID (int*, auto increment, unsigned zerofill, primary key)
        memberID (int*, FK: TABLE user)
        date (datetime)

    TABLE stat
        statID (int*, auto increment, unsigned zerofill, primary key)
        readingID (int*, FK: TABLE reading)
        type (varchar, 3)*
        value (decimal 4.1)*
```

`*` These datatypes are up to you based on what makes sense, just make sure primary and foreign keys match up.

A `stat` is a measurement (e.g. height, weight, bodyfat, etc.)  A `reading` is defined as one or more `stat` measurements taken at the same time.

Note this all is within the same database and it contains three tables.

Answer (score 0):

Having multiple tables with the same structure is almost always a bad idea, as it will prevent you from accessing the data from multiple such tables in a canonical form. Say you want the average weight difference between summer and winter, then you'd have to iterate over all tables if you split them by user.

I'm not sure where you see “excess redundancy” in your approach. But perhaps you would be more comfortable with a table which has the various parameters as columns instead of values of an enum column. I.e. introduce columns ht, wt, fat, wat and whatever else you might need. That way, you are not restricted to a single numeric type for all of these values, and you don't store values of completely unrelated units in the same column. You can still use `NULL` for missing values, so you won't be forced to always supply all values if that isn't a policy you want to enforce. As the whole set would have date and person appear only once, it only makes sense if you usually do multiple readings on a single person.

Comment: I see what you are saying about splitting data across tables.

Comment: What I saw as excess redundancy in my first example was that to keep records for only two people, for each day that we take measurements, there would be at least 8 entries added to the table, all of them would have the same date and 4 would have the same member id (and the other 4 the other id). This gets worse and worse the bigger the family, the more characteristics you are tracking (blood sugar, etc), the frequency of adding records, and how long the records go back. I did consider having a column for each measurement, but discarded it because of the nulling issue.

Comment: As for the data types, 4/1 decimal seems to work fine for all types: ht=63.5 (my php script knows ht=inches), wt=118.2 (wt=lbs via php), wat=53.2 (wat=% php), fat=25.6 (fat=% php). Fat and water will never be over 100% and don't need more than one decimal point of accuracy, and ht and wt will never need more than 3 digits nor more than one point of accuracy. It may make sense to have a table matching the measurement types to their units, but I'm not really sure about this yet.

Comment: Those 8 rows would still be 8 rows if split over two tables, so your splitting suggestion doesn't reduce redundancy there. If you worry about `NULL`s eating too much space, you can create the table with variable row lengths. Then there will be only a single byte to indicate the `NULL`ness of up to eight columns, with no additional space for those columns. For `ENGINE=MyISAM` specify `ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC`. I'm not sure about `InnoDB` internals.

Comment: With the answer supplied by jedwards, there are two entries in the readings table and 8 in the stats table, the difference being that the date is entered only twice (allowing different datetime values for different users) instead of 8 times. Being that the date is the largest chunk of data, it seems to me that adding an extra table (in the same db) as a date reference between the users and their stats will save lots of storage space in the long run. I am using InnoDB. Normalization standards would have me add the extra table rather than enter the date 8 times or null a bunch of columns.

Comment: I see no normal form violation in NULL columns either. As for storage requirements, due to the required keys and the indexes that go with them, I doubt that the approach using another table will use significantly less space, but the whole db should be fairly small if you're only dealing with a single family. No need to over-optimize there, I think.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form : "Violation of any of these conditions would mean that the table is not strictly relational, and therefore that it is not in 1NF. Examples of tables (or views) that would not meet this definition of 1NF are: A table with at least one nullable attribute. A nullable attribute would be in violation of condition 4, which requires every field to contain exactly one value from its column's domain. It...is controversial...Codd's later vision of the relational model...made explicit provision for nulls. I guess I'm on the non-null side of the controversy.

Comment: The db will be very small at the outset (for my family), but once I have been tracking stats for a while, that date column would add bulk fast if it's entered 4 times for every user, every day or even week. I am, however hoping I can make this useful enough to clean it up and make it available to others who may have large families or households (group homes, for example). The date column also violates 1NF if repeated 4 times in the same column for each user.